# Google MAP not showing in chrome

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-os

I have an MVC4 application that plots GPS coordinates to a google MAP loading within a twitter bootstrap modal. My problem is that the map sometimes loads all of it's tiles (sometimes NOT) when using IE 10 as seen in the image below.

[image]

The map doesn't show at all in Chrome version 27.

[image]

Here is the HTML code for the map

```
<div id="VehicleMovementModal" class="modal hide fade">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Vehicle movement for the last 24 hours</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="mapCanvas" class="mapCanvas">
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="VehicleMovementLinkContainer" class="VehicleMovementLinkContainer">
    <i class="icon-download-alt"></i> <a href="~/Vehicle/GetGPSCoordinateCSV?vehicleId=@vehicleModel.VehicleData.Id&hours=24">Export GPS coordinates for the last 24 hours</a>
    <br />
    <i class="icon-download-alt"></i> <a href="~/Vehicle/GetGPSCoordinateCSV?vehicleId=@vehicleModel.VehicleData.Id&hours=48">Export GPS coordinates for the last 48 hours</a>
</div>
```

How I call the javascript from within my HTML page

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=aaaaaaa&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/PlotVehicleMovement.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
</script>
```

and the javascript I'm using to draw the map

```
function initialize() {

var gpsCoordinateCollection = $('#gpsCoordinates').val().split(',');

if (gpsCoordinateCollection.length > 0) {

    // The last GPS coordinates received + the date it was received.
    var gpsCoordinatePacket = gpsCoordinateCollection[0].split(';');

    if (gpsCoordinatePacket.length > 0) {

        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(gpsCoordinatePacket[0], gpsCoordinatePacket[1]),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapProp);

        plotVehicleMovement(map, gpsCoordinateCollection);
    }
  }
}

function plotVehicleMovement(map, gpsCoordinateCollection) {

// Define the clickable area of the markers.
var shape = {
    coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
};

var polyLineLatLongCollection = [];

for (var i = 0; i < gpsCoordinateCollection.length; i++) {

    var gpsCoordinatePacket = gpsCoordinateCollection[i].split(';');

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(gpsCoordinatePacket[0], gpsCoordinatePacket[1]);

    polyLineLatLongCollection.push(latLng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 4,
            strokeColor: '#F5B71A'
        },
        shape: shape
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}

var polyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: polyLineLatLongCollection,
    strokeColor: '#F5B71A',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1
});

polyLine.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that my map is contained within a twitter bootstrap modal div, which is hidden from the user until a link is clicked. My google maps height and width is specified to be a percentage relative to that of it's containing parent. Therefore I had to include the following javascript function to make sure that my map is resized when the modal is displayed.

```
function ResizeMap() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}
```

and I added this jquery function to trigger the resize

```
$("#VehicleMovementModal").on('shown', function () {
    ResizeMap();
});
```

Now everything is working as expected.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you, I've been struggling with this for quite a while.